# cliente guzzle laravel

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

Estoy usando laravel 5.8 con guzzle para consumir una API.

Con POSTMAN obtengo el `acces_token`, pero no lo obtengo con guzzle.

Estoy enviando lo siguiente desde el controlador:

```
public function test(Request $request){
    $username = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $url = "http://x.x.x.x/api/auth/login";
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url,   ['debug'   => false],  [
        'stream' => true,<br>
        'headers'        => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                            'X-Requested-With' => ' MLHttpRequest',
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'remember_me'=>true
        ]
    ]);
```

Y la respuesta es:

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response {#242 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:7 [▼
    "Date" => array:1 [▶]
    "Server" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-Powered-By" => array:1 [▶]
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [▶]
    "Set-Cookie" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkM5aUVrVGpBZmdJNklucXJ6WUVMWlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZytobDV0alEwcVNLd1I0KzNPdUpUbkZGcm12T0ZTdXJzQTdGSXNaZnVkUnhRNHFSNkd1ckFWbTRKeFJhU3RZUEpLV05WV ▶"
      1 => "laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IldWTzkvY0ZtQkJoMDJhUHBhd0JEQkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUTIxcU8ycERBUk1FR3U2RzYwOTBoNGhqdHdsanI3N1FnQUJUU2RGKzVOWXdHdnZnb3ZaKzNqaXBUZHBHWUJ1dDI3 ▶"
    ]
    "Transfer-Encoding" => array:1 [▶]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:7 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#239 ▶}
}
```

Obtengo código `200`, o sea que el login estuvo bien, pero ¿Cómo obtengo el `access_token`, para usarlo en el proximo request?

Si pruebo con Postman, veo el acces_token

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMWZhOWZiYTgzN2RkNDAzZGY1MDllZWE4OGY3ZDM5NjhiMjdlMTU2MjRlYzFjZWFhNjViYzVjOGI4NTljZGJmYjBhNzcwY2I5OGMxNGQ2MTkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MzU3NzM2MjMuNjkxMjg2LCJuYmYiOjE2MzU3NzM2MjMuNjkxMjg5LCJleHAiOjE2NjczMDk2MjMuNjg4NzA2LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.VBPldppX_Y6SZwS7k06pDo8VrFCpIPxgjGjyEPqlEBousN9VXGHhSjnmUUt6XEJZKGZEcCA6ETICXTAF9UGws5GW4KwQax22GhaQQ-XTSCxt21S0tWZZQj0lJo_1VWsZ6w3W7gbGsjc15n9iN0gn8rtkp3y3C_qGfhjtYodnqDSDkqzbziLmA0LyATlo5n82akMM8nRntSJ30IYxnwmvDKQs9HvEmWyDur8sUugWrsXTYbak9gBZUrWZ1z2gWTFgxS4vHWVlOOX4DMIdI4a1dQncb4IAhgvvtN-InWy_0r_IhsUUnmcVPk0J8xq5EtsRWFduR61RwJcFlm8WmgSfLoseSXjpbaluD25uZU4q5XlSnx6-8Ft0gj9Ws3eofoUg0sasHW6ueUGeYbPzi9EB7MhrCsOVFNpJ6IgN9-cIPhf4dkddD8gjigVrNpKspj3OKx8jo8Qae7LshxumA7sYQzlB_GPWFE_eKxLkN8k4lu0b70NTotz8TV_a3UwXQuYD_UzzV_ig7UdIMDvHNP6nr1khBVNM1hSUg9qu2UKuO0sKRImv2YxsHVsrmufw-IvxmxphomyfjbWwc0sCZwAkJM3itor3ogvMMgXcJdGCIseAPBAnD-RrsqjdqIOSqRpVIU1ukos0sudg2Me-ImndUQA9ttlQ5gvakq4LxkA1_uY",
    "token_type": "Bearer",    
    "expires_at": "2021-11-08 13:33:43"
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Una vez que tienes el objeto Response de guzzle, solo tienes que llamar a sus métodos ->getBody()->getcontents() para ver el contenido de la respuesta. Debería ser un array con el token. Por supuesto recuerda mirar el status del o neto response, no sea que te dé un 500 u otro distinto.

Comment: dd($response->getBody()->getcontents());<br> Esto me devuelve un codigo html de la pagina laravel<br> y return $response->getBody()->getcontents();<br> me devuelve la pagina welcome de laravel<br>

Answer (score 0):

**Este me funcionó**

```
public function login(Request $request){ 
    $username = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    $url = "http://x.x.x.x/api/auth/login";
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'remember_me'=>true
        ]
    ]);
    $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();<br>
```

}